# PermissionRequiredMixin with django view method

Tags: html, django, model-view-controller, view, django-views

I know, that we have a PermissionRequiredMixin and it has got permission_required.

I have a question, how to do that with on django view method.

Thank you, guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with the [**`@permission_required(…)`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('permission_name')
def some_view(request):
    # …
```

you can also pass an iterable of permissions:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required(['permission_name1', 'permission_name2'])
def some_view(request):
    # …
```